# Change width of primefaces dialog

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I want to increase the width of a primefaces dialog which is already shown. The user clicks on a link/button, the dialog gets extended in the width and shows some more content.
All approaches I tried were not successful:

1.: change with jquery:

```
$('theFormId\\:theDialogId').css('width', 1000);
```

2.: refer p:dialog width attribute to a backing bean value:

```
<p:dialog width="#{myBean.dialogWidth}"...
```

When the link/button is clicked, the backing bean dialogWidth member is changed and the dialog is updated. Unfortunately this closes the dialog.

Is there a possiblity to "live" resize an already displayed dialog?

I am using PF 5.1.16 and JSF 2.2.10

Regards
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

Set width's value from bean and button to set width

```
<h1>Dialog width</h1>

<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="editBtnWF" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                            title="WF-R" update="@form"
                            action="#{testBacking.setWidth}"
                            oncomplete="PF('dlg2').show();">
                        </p:commandButton>



    <p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" id="dlg" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true"
         width="#{testBacking.dlgwidth}">

        <p:inputText value="#{testBacking.dlgwidth}"></p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton id="ee" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                            title="WF-R" update="dlg"
                            action="#{testBacking.setWidth}"
                            oncomplete="PF('dlg2').show();">
                        </p:commandButton>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Or try putting `update="@form"`, It works for me

Where in bean is like:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBacking implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer dlgwidth=500;

    public void setWidth(){
        System.out.println("TestBacking : dlgwidth = "+dlgwidth);
    }
    public Integer getDlgwidth() {
        return dlgwidth;
    }

    public void setDlgwidth(Integer dlgwidth) {
        this.dlgwidth = dlgwidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. There is no update of the dialog. So the change of the width in the backing bean has no impact on the dialog. If I close the dialog and open it afterwards, the dialog has the new width.

Comment: Basically this works, but I think it is a hack. I do not like that the dialog is closed and opened afterwards. Sideeffect is that text which was entered in inputTexts will be reset to the backing bean values. Not submitted user entries will be lost. For this an ajax based immediate submit would be the solution, but I think this leads to custom validation when the dialog save button is clicked because all values are already in the backing bean.

Answer (score 0):

actually you dont need to increase width of the dialog, if you update the content inside  dialog it will automatically change width to fit its content

however you can change width

```
<p:dialog id="dlg" width="#{bean.widthValue}">
      ---contents-----
</p:dialog>

<p:commandButton  update="dlg" 
                  process="@this" 
                  actionListener="#{bean.changeWidth()}" />
```

in your bean

```
int widthValue;
public void changeWidth(){
   this.widthValue=500;
}
```

Comment: The click on the commandButton (commandLink in my case) closes the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I mapped the dialog width and height from the backing bean how described in the answers here. The update of the form/dialog closes the dialog. I used the omnifaces  tag to keep the entered user data in the form during the dialog closing and opening.